# Class.prototype.aFunction() vs Class.aFunction()

Tags: javascript, prototype

In example code:

```
var Class = function() {

}

Class.prototype.nonStaticFunction = function() {

}

Class.staticFunction = function() {

}
```

Is there a speed, memory, or any other significant characteristics of `staticFunction` over `nonStaticFunction`?

I believe that `staticFunction` have below characteristics but I'm sure I'm missing some and I want to know learn when to use one over another.

- `this` keyword will be the `Class` function not the object.
- can be used without instantiation of `Class` object.

Comment: One is an instance method that is called on a given instance of the object `obj.method()`, the other is a static method that is just called as a normal namespaced function `Class.func()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These have entirely different use cases

```
Class.staticFunction; // function () {...}, `this` defaults to `Class`
Class.nonStaticFunction; // undefined
```

So if we want to use `Class` as a *namespace*, you'd choose the style you call *"staticFunction"*

```
(new Class).staticFunction; // undefined
(new Class).nonStaticFunction; // function () {...}, `this instanceof Class`
```

So if we want to use `Class` as a *constructor*, you'd choose the style you call *"nonStaticFunction"*

- In both cases there are no new instances of *staticFunction* or *nonStaticFunction* created after define time, so memory usage is the same.
- Object lookup is done by hashtable in native code, [**[[GetProperty]]**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) will be unnoticably different no matter where in the prototype chain the key is found.
- Creating instances is more expensive than not creating instances, but if you need to create something anyway then there is no gain or loss in time spent.

---

*JavaScript doesn't really have classes*, these are a structure from classical languages but *JavaScript* is a *prototypical language*.

All we have in *JavaScript* are *Objects*, and these *Objects* can be linked together in two different ways

- By properties (what you're probably used to), e.g.

  ```
  foo = {};
  foo.bar = {};
  foo.bar.baz = {fizz: 'buzz'};
  foo.bar.baz.fizz; // "buzz"
  ```
- By the prototype chain, e.g.

  ```
  baz = {fizz: 'buzz'};
  bar = Object.create(baz);
  foo = Object.create(bar);
  foo.fizz; // "buzz" via
  // no own _fizz_ on `foo`
  // no own _fizz_ on `bar`    ( = Object.getPrototypeOf(foo) )
  // own _fizz_ found on `baz` ( = Object.getPrototypeOf(bar) )
  ```

The [*ES 6* `class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) is *syntactical sugar* for defining a *Constructor* with a *prototype* longhand as you would in *ES 5*.

---

*Java* and *JavaScript* are entirely different languages, don't think they're similar because of their names.

Comment: I see that, I guess I should have refined my question more.  In Java there is a preference for static methods for less memory footprint and etc.  Is there such advantage for this `staticFunction` in javascript??

Comment: Absolutely agree the java to js is like bread to tennis shoes, not related.  "Creating instances is more expensive than not creating instances, but if you need to create something anyway then there is no gain or loss in time spent."  is more along the line of what I was looking for.